# DC motor modelling with Bond Graph

Tags: motor, robot-model

I am trying to construct an equation that describes the output torque as a function of lambda  and omega
I have obtained the following bond graph but I am unsure of how to proceed.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might help to organize the equations a little in steps.  I think you have all this above:

Output torque of system:

> $\tau_F$

Output torque at motor:

> $\tau_0 = \tau_F/N$

Motor output speed:

> $\omega_a = N\omega_M$

Motor torque speed relationship$^{*}$:

> $\displaystyle{\frac{K_m}{R}}V_{in} = \frac{L}{R}\displaystyle{\frac{d\tau_0}{dt}} + \displaystyle{\frac{K_m^2}{R}}\omega_a$

I think it is also correct to state that:

> $\lambda = LI_a$

This doesn't quite answer your question, but maybe gives you some new ideas.

---

$^{*}$ See, e.g., Harry Asada, Introduction to Robotics, [Chapter 2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-12-introduction-to-robotics-fall-2005/lecture-notes/chapter2.pdf)